# Switching between power source

Tags: power-supply, batteries, amplifier, switching

I'm making this speaker where I have 2 12v batteries in series giving 24v an amp. 
and a PSU giving 24v to the same amp.

I wanna make a circuit that switches off the batterie link between each other and the Amp when the PSU Is live.

so only the PSU is giving power to the Amp

:D

Comment: sorry i mean they are in series :/

Comment: Okay i also thought about a mosfet :D

Comment: btw. u dont have a link for a mosfet that will work?  and thanks for helping :D

Comment: Power a 24V relay off the PSU and use it to switch either battery or PSU to the amp.

Comment: okay :D will look into that

Comment: u dont have a schematic on how that will be connected? Brian. and thanks for helping

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/ycegbs39